# how to create a list appears from the bottom in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

how can I do a list like this ?
can you give me the name of the method ?
is it PickerView ?

I want a filed ruled City Name and when clicked in ..
a list from the bottom appears

[see the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m07Fq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should use `UIPickerView`. And set datasource and delegate methods. This is small [example](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/).

Some key points of the implementation.

```
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(row)"
    }
}

extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func  pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you .. can you send to me a video tutorial ? I'm a beginner so I want more details

Comment: I add link to the example

Comment: the example is a simple picker view (not what I want) .. did you see the pic I post ? I want the list coming from the button when you click to the filed .. hope I can explain it well

Comment: It is just animation that is added to the picker view.

Comment: This what you a looking for just implement simple API https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Comment: how can I do that ? I don't find any tutorial